# Unit Tests Failure in TFS Build Machine Due to AppDomain.CurrentDomain

Tags: testing, build, tfs

I'm facing a problem with my unit tests not running in my TFS Build Machine, although they are running on my developer machine.

I get an exception on the following line, trying to load all my loaded assemblies for a specific interface:

```
    var classesToMap = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList()
        .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
        .Where(p => typeof(IInterface).IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsClass).ToList();
```

The exception is:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or
>   more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property
>   for more information..

Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried catching the exception and see whats inside the LoaderExceptions property ?

Comment: This is the exception within the LoaderExceptions (take in mind that I'm using TFS Express Beta (2011):

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamSystem.Licensing, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got this fixed by adding a condition to discard all dlls which are in the GAC:

```
 var classesToMap = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .Where(a => !a.GlobalAssemblyCache)
        .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
        .Where(p => typeof(IInterface).IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsClass).ToList();
```

It's a work around but does the work for me.

Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem but I'm already not using the assemblies on GAC... your suggestion did not work for me unfortunately. Is there any other workaround you are familiar with?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the only assembly that failed to load was `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamSystem.Licensing` which is a dependency of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common`.

Based on [Osel Miko Dřevorubec's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22355881/2498426), I came up with this safer strategy:

```
private static Type[] GetTypesFromAssemblySafe(Assembly assembly)
{
    var ignoredAssemblies = new List<string>()
        {
            "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common" //Gives trouble in TFS automated builds
        };

    if (!ignoredAssemblies.Contains(assembly.FullName.Split(',')[0]))
        return assembly.GetTypes();
    else
        return new Type[] { };
}

var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .ToList()
    .SelectMany(GetTypesFromAssemblySafe);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also met thiss issue but @nirpi condition didnt helped me i used this solution succesfully:

```
private static Type[] GetTypesFromAssemblySafe(Assembly assembly) {
    try {
        return assembly.GetTypes();
    } catch {
        return new Type[] {};
    }
}

var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .ToList()
    .SelectMany(GetTypesFromAssemblySafe);
```

source : http://www.kspace.pt/posts/dynamic-type-discovery/